# Inserting line by line into SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, razor, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I have a `*.TXT` file full of about 1 - 200 lines. Each line is just a name of a City/Suburb, and am trying to insert each line in this file into the database.

I put it all in a Try/Catch block, because it didn't work, but nothing appears when I output details of the exception, if there is one at all.

I have confirmed that I can insert 1 record at a time with just this line:

```
db.Execute("insert into SuburbsPostCodesAndStates (Suburb, State) values (@0, @1)", "lol", "nsw");
```

The code I have that I am using to insert these lines, is:

```
@{
    var message = "";
    var db = Database.Open("SSSCCC");

    try
    {
        if(File.Exists(Href("~/NSW.txt")))
        {
            string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(Href("~/NSW.txt"));

            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader( text ))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    db.Execute("insert into SuburbsPostCodesAndStates (Suburb, State) values (@0, @1)", line, "NSW");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        message = exception.Message;
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @message
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I go about this?

Any help at all is much appreciated.

Thank you

## Solution:

```
@{  
    var message = "";  
    var db = Database.Open("SSSCCC");  

    try  
    {  
        if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath("NSW.txt")))  
        {  
            string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("NSW.txt"));  

            if(text.Length == 0) { throw new Exception("File does not contain any lines"); }

            foreach(string line in text)  
            {  
                db.Execute("insert into SuburbsPostCodesAndStates (Suburb, State) values (@0, @1)", line, "NSW");  

            }  
        }  
        else 
        { 
          throw new Exception("File does not exist"); 
        } 
    }  
    catch(Exception exception)  
    {  
        message = exception.Message;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: @p.campbell - I am using SQL Server Compact which comes with WebMatrix.

Comment: Maybe you should consider BULK INSERT instead of calling 100s of separate insert statements...

Comment: Can't Bulk insert into a WebMatrix SQL Compact DB (which is why I almost decided not to use WebMatrix) _unless you first migrate the compact db to the one provided by your hosting company, but I can't do that yet._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a StringReader here... try this instead.

```
@{ 
          var message = ""; 
    var db = Database.Open("SSSCCC"); 
    try 
    { 
        if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/NSW.txt"))) 
        { 
            string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/NSW.txt")); 
            if(text.Length == 0) throw new Exception("File does not contain any lines");
            foreach(string line in text) 
            { 
                db.Execute("insert into SuburbsPostCodesAndStates (Suburb, State) values (@0, @1)", line, "NSW"); 

            } 
        } 
        else
        {
          throw new Exception("File does not exist");
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception exception) 
    { 
        message = exception.Message; 

    } 
}
```

Comment: I added some exceptions, give it another go and see if any of these exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Damn it! I knew I shoulve put that else clause in there. It says "File does not exist.". It's obviously lying... But atleast I know it's not looking in the right place now. Thanks for that @Chris Gessler

Comment: I also noticed you're using an Href() method, not sure what that does, but Server.MapPath() will provide the physical path from a relative path.

Comment: Yep, I changed it to Server.MapPath() right after I got the not exist exception. Href() is a WebMatrix/Razor thing makes it easier and less tedius with file paths.

Comment: Ok, so I just checked it out again with Server.MapPath - but now it gives me this error: "_Could not find file 'C:\NSW.txt'. _"

Comment: I've got it now. It's working. Am posting solution now. Thanks heaps for your help.